# Azure Active Directory AcquireTokenAsync doesn't trigger event

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, azure-active-directory

Based on this tutorial http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/08/28/use-adal-to-connect-your-universal-apps-to-azure-ad-or-adfs/ I'm trying to connect my universal application with Azure Active Directory. Unfortunelly Windows Phone 8.1 app isn't working entirely right.

Everything wents okay (I can login sucessfully when I click twice button, because the second time he is getting "silent" token and method AfterLogin is perfomed) but the event in function AcquireTokenAsync isn't trigered after I put my credentials in window.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var result = await ac.AcquireTokenSilentAsync("https://graph.windows.net", ClientId);
    if (result != null && result.Status == AuthenticationStatus.Success)
        AfterLogin(result);
    else
        ac.AcquireTokenAndContinue("https://graph.windows.net", ClientId, WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri(), AfterLogin);
}

public void AfterLogin(AuthenticationResult result)
{
    if (result.Status == AuthenticationStatus.Success)
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(HubPage));
}
```

What is wrong that the AfterLogin isn't perfomed after ac.AcquireTokenAndContinue() end it's work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the Windows Phone sample https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-WindowsPhone8.1 as starting point? Does the sample work on its own, before integrating it in the universal app solution? I would recommend adding breakpoints in the App.xaml.cs code to ensure that the continuation events are correctly hooked up.

Comment: I use this sample https://xaml.codeplex.com/releases/view/136763
I didn't have a single WP8.1 solution, I had from start Universal App.
I ensured and continuation events in app.xaml.cs are correctly hooking up.

Comment: Problem solved. It tourns out that I shouldn't create many objects of adal library. The key is to create everything in App.xaml.cs and then only pass it to login page, main page, etc.